# li hover on navigation menu

Tags: html, css, hover

I am simply trying to get there to be a li:hover function that turns background of one list item black on hover. Please see my jsFiddle at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ATX9f/)

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul class="nav">
    <li id="home">home</li>
    <li id="about">about</li>
    <li id="blog">blog</li>
    <li id="contact">contact</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a

```
position:relative;
z-index:999;
```

to the `.nav` element

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ATX9f/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidebar .nav li:hover {
   background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `:before` and `:after` are covering the `li`s that's why you can't hover them. your hover code is correct.

fixed using `z-index` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HWAPh/)